# Align of Numbered Circle and Line

Tags: html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/modakindia/1Lz8bcmt/3/):
The CSS is below:

```css
    .listicle {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
    }

    .listicle li {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .circle {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: #3498db;
      border-radius: 50%;
      color: #fff;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      padding: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<section class="text-black fs-5" style="font-family: Cambria, serif, sans-serif;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Deposits and Withdrawls for Post Office Savings Account</h1>
    <ul class="listicle">
      <li>
        <div class="circle">1</div>
        <div>Minimum Deposit to Open:
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>  
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="circle">2</div>
        <div>Subsequent Deposits:
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>  
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="circle">3</div>
        <div>Minimum Deposit to Open:
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>  
      </li>      
    </ul>  
  </div>  
</section>
```

I need the position of circle in line to List heading [Such as Minimum Deposit to Open:, Subsequent Deposits: and Minimum Deposit to Open:].

Further I also need a line is to be connected in between circles. There may be long text within p tag. It is available in the fiddle.

Regards,

Swarup.

Answer (score 1):

## Circle position

To have the position of the circle inline with respect List heading, consider applying `align-self: start` to the `.circle` element:

```css
.circle {
  …
  align-self: start;
}
```

## Connection lines

For a line to connect in-between the circles, have a new `<div>` element in each `<li>` element:

```html
<li>
  …
  <div class="line"></div>
```

Apply `position: relative` to each `<li>`. This will make the `<li>` elements a position container that we'll need in the next step:

```css
.listicle li {
  …
  position: relative;
}
```

Draw the lines using the `.line` elements via CSS:

```css
.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px; /* = [30px .circle height] + [40px .circle padding-top] + [40px .circle padding-bottom] */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 55px; /* = ([15px .circle width] ÷ 2) + [40px .circle padding-left] */
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

Apply `flex-shrink: 0` to `.circle` so that it never shrinks in width, so that the connecting line is always guaranteed to be centered relative to the `.circle` elements:

```css
.circle {
  …
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```css
.listicle {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.listicle li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  align-self: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 55px;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section
  class="text-black fs-5"
  style="font-family: Cambria, serif, sans-serif"
>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Deposits and Withdrawls for Post Office Savings Account</h1>
    <ul class="listicle">
      <li>
        <div class="circle">1</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div>
          Minimum Deposit to Open:
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
            ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
            and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
            only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
            with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
            and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
            PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
            ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
            and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
            only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
            with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
            and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
            PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="circle">2</div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div>
          Subsequent Deposits:
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
            ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
            and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
            only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
            with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
            and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
            PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="circle">3</div>
        <div>
          Minimum Deposit to Open:
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
            ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
            and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
            only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
            with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
            and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
            PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
            ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
            and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not
            only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
            remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
            with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
            and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
            PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!! Extremely sorry for delay response.